# PIC performance in static libraries

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, position-independent-code

I'm using `yaml-cpp` library, which by default generates position dependent static library (`libyaml-cpp.a`). My own library compiles into two versions, static and shared. Since I need shared one, I have to turn on PIC for the `yaml-cpp` (that's the easy part). Now however, do I suffer performance hit in the static library? If yes, how big?

Basically, I have three options:

1. compile `yaml-cpp` twice, once position dependent and once PIC, link appropriate onces into mine shared and static library

   - Pros: probably best perfomance wise, both mine shared and static and use same object files (meaning .cpp are compiled only once)
   - Cons: probably most setup, `yaml-cpp` will be compiled twice but that should not matter, I'll be not changing it (that often)
2. compile `yaml-cpp` once as PIC, link it into mine shared (PIC) and static (not PIC)

   - Pros: easy to setup
   - Cons: source codes need to compile twice (shared (PIC), static (non PIC))
3. compile `yaml-cpp` once as PIC and compile both mine (shared & static) as PIC too

   - Pros: easy to setup
   - Cons: slight perfomance hit in static one?

So the option 1 seems like the best one. Do I have any false assumptions in my summary? Or did I miss any other option?

Platform: amd64

Comment: If you haven't already used a profiler to profile each of the scenarios you have presented you really should do that.

Comment: I'm just setting up a build system, don't really have anything to profile yet

Comment: Well the only way you're going to get a definitive answer on performance is to run it in a profiler. Probably best to do first rather than asking people to speculate on what the outcome might be.

Comment: point to asking this question was that I'm surely not the first one to encounter this problem

Comment: The actual architecture that you are targeting is quite relevant for the question. We run these tests for some of our own code and the impact (for our own code, mileage can vary) was minimal for x86_64, but quite noticeable for SPARC, with x86_32 somewhere in between.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas oh, good point, I added the architecture. mostly targeting amd64.

Comment: While that may be true it's still a reflection of the lack of research and investigation done on your part. If you had does that part of the research you would already have your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The downside to PIC is a modest degradation in application performance (often 5 to 15 percent)